# Matplotlib notebook cropped figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to make an interactive script in jupyter notebook that will draw different images in cycle and asks for user decision. I came to the point where I can redraw figure with 3 subplots, but have no idea how to configure the size of interactive figure to make all subplots visible. As you can see only part of the second subplot peeps out from the right.

I will be grateful for any help.

[image: cropped figure with 3 subplots]

Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
% matplotlib notebook

fig, [ax1, ax2, ax3] = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(5, 5))
ax1.set_xlabel("src")
ax2.set_xlabel("rgb")
ax3.set_xlabel("hsv")
ax2.set_xlim([-1,257])
ax3.set_xlim([-1,257])
plt.legend(loc='upper right')

color = ('r','g','b') # HSV colors
labels = ('h', 's', 'v')  

plt.subplots_adjust(right = 2.3) 

for i in range(0,3):
  im = cv2.imread("image.png")
  im_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  im_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
  ax1.imshow(im_rgb, cmap='gray')
  for i,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([im_rgb],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
    ax2.plot(histr, color = col, label=col)
  for i,col in enumerate(color):
    histr = cv2.calcHist([im_hsv],[i],None,[256],[0,256])
    ax3.plot(histr, color = col, label=labels[i])
  fig.canvas.draw()  
  answer = input("Next? " )
```

Comment: No it is not, I will correct this now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not be obvious from the [`subplots_adjust` documentation](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html), but the parameters for `top` and `right` need to be smaller than 1 to have the axes stay within the figure boundaries, as those parameters are the **fraction** of figure height and width at which the figure margin starts.

If you provide `right=2.3` it will mean that the last subplot's right edge ends at 2.3 times the figure width - which is most probably undesired.

[image]

So keep `right` below `1` and to make all plots fit inside the figure, you may want to adjust the figure size instead, e.g. `figsize=(13,5)`.